# Custom Description in Google Map Marker

Tags: javascript, mysql, asp.net, google-maps

how to customize the description part of google maps marker description parameter.

```
        "title": '<%# Eval("country") %>',
        "lat": '<%# Eval("Latitude") %>',
        "lng": '<%# Eval("Longitude") %>',
        "description": 'Location : <%# Eval("City") %>,<%# Eval("country") %>,<%# Eval("Latitude") %>,<%# Eval("Longitude") %>'
```

This is the output that i'm looking for for each data to be displayed on the next line -

```
Location: Name of a city
Country : Name of a Country
Latitude:
Longitude:
```

Please help! Thanks Guys :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need is an `InfoWindow`. These are basically containers that contain HTML and pop up at a certain point on the map.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0)
});
marker.description = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content:"HTML Content goes here"
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
  this.description.setPosition(this.getPosition());
  this.description.open(map); //map to display on
});
```

1. Define a marker with whatever properties you want.
2. Make the "description" window for that marker, with HTML content that will be displayed like normal HTML. If using CSS styles, make sure to specify that the names will be inside whatever `div` contains the map.
3. Make an event listener that displays the `InfoWindow` on the map, at the spot where the marker is, when the marker is clicked.